# input from txt and write to excel

Tags: java

I am coding JAVA for input data from txt and pattern check if match then put that value to xlsx file with specific form. and input file count is more than hundred.. How can I get result like I want? please review my code and help me
the result that I want is like below.(below is just sample. real xlsx row go more than 100,000
[the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMbiS.png)

The result I got is like below.
[The result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuXeK.png)

the java code that I am making is below.

```
    File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();
    for(File f: listFiles){
    if(f.isFile()){
        if(f.getName().contains(".log")){

           System.out.println("###"+f.getName()+"###");
           try{
             scan = new Scanner(f);
             int NE_CNT =1;
                 int Time_CNT =1;

                 Pattern NE_PT = Pattern.compile("(\\D{2})(\\d{1})(\\D{4,5})(\\d{3})");
             Pattern NE_TIME_PT = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\D{3}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})");

            while(scan.hasNext()){  
              String Line = scan.nextLine();
            Matcher NE_MC = NE_PT.matcher(Line);
            Matcher NE_TIME_MC = NE_TIME_PT.matcher(Line);
            if(NE_MC.find()){
              row_NE = spreadsheet.createRow(NE_CNT);
              NE_CELL_DATA = row_NE.createCell(0);
              NE_CELL_DATA.setCellValue(NE_MC.group());
              NE_CNT++;
            }

            if(NE_TIME_MC.find()){
             row_Time = spreadsheet.createRow(Time_CNT);
             TIME_CELL_DATA = row_Time.createCell(1);
             TIME_CELL_DATA.setCellValue(NE_TIME_MC.group());
             Time_CNT++;        
            }           
        }       
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
     }
   }
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
   workbook.close();
 }
}
```